# Could not load file or assembly `SQLitePCL` when testing MobileServiceSQLiteStore

Tags: android, sqlite, azure, azure-mobile-services, xamarin-studio

## Could not load file or assembly `SQLitePCL` when unit test accesses MobileServiceSQLiteStore

I have been trying to build my first Microsoft Azure WebAPI for a Mobile application following the Azure getting started instructions here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

; the mobile app makes use of the offline sync (push, pull) of the MobileServiceSQLiteStore class. The problem I have is I keep getting the `could not load...SQLitePCL` error. I've spent 2 full days on this now, and have read many similar stack overflow questions, very similar, but none that help with this problem.

The goal, beyond simply getting past this error (in case there's a more pragmatic work around) is to be able to write integration (acceptance tests) and unit tests that test my code that I will write to wrap the MobileServiceSqlLiteStore class.

No matter what I do, I cannot get the `db.DefineTable<xxDTO>();` to work in a windows console or unit test running under windows. 
When I run the following code;

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void can_create_db_and_create_table()
{
    var filename = @"d:\test\testdb.db3";
    SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();                // this excecutes -> raw.SetProvider((ISQLite3Provider) new SQLite3Provider_esqlite3());
    var db = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(filename);
    db.DefineTable<Person>();
}
```

I always get the following error -> **`Could not load file or assembly SQLitePCL version 3.8.7.2`**

### steps to reproduce issue

1. install SQLITE (3) runtime and tools ; sqlite-winrt-3130000.vsix (download from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html )
2. create new class project, .Net 4.5.1
3. add the following packages

   - `install-package SQLitePCL.bundle_green  -version 0.9.3`
   - `Install-package System.Data.SQLite      -version 1.0.102.0`
   - `Install-package nunit                   -version 3.4.1`
4. run the unit test shown above.

System.Data.SQLite works easily enough, but that is not compatible with the version of Sqlite that installed on Android. i.e. the following code runs easily on windows;

```
[Test]
public void prove_we_can_perform_normal_system_data_sqllite_commands()

{
 var path = @"d:\test\provedb2.db";
 File.Create(path).Dispose();
 using (var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={path};Version=3;"))
        {
           conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("create table customer (name, tel, add1, add2, id UNIQUE)",conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

... but this is not compatible with the functionality provided on Adroid and via MobileServiceSQLiteStore class.

If I decompile `MobileServiceSQLiteStore` class using dot net Reflector, I can confirm that `MobileServiceSQLiteStore` appears to be a wrapper around `SQLitePCL` classes. 
If I run the following unit test, I get the same error as when I try to access the `MobileServiceSQLiteStore` class, which is why I was hoping that it should be possible to access this class when not running inside/on Android?

```
[Test]
public void show_MobileServiceSQLiteStore_gives_same_error_as_SQLLitePCL_which_it_wraps()
{

    var path = @"provedb2.db";
    using (var db = new  SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={path};Version=3;"))
    {
        var cmd = db.Prepare("create table customer (name, tel, add1, add2, id UNIQUE)");
        cmd.Step();
    }
    // this fails with Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3.dll' >>> aargh!            
}
```

It seems absurd to have such a monster god class and not be able to unit test it, or create a safe wrapper around it?

p.s. my development machine is a clean windows 7 professional, with a clean, fresh and up to date Visual studio 2015, provisioned specifically for this project.

Any advice or suggestions on how I can run this class on windows  will be super SUPER appreciated! i.e. how to get past the 'Could not load file or assembly SQLitePCL' error.

thanks all in advance.

best regards,

Alan

Comment: I've created a sandbox play solution with three projects that show the problem, with the single unit test that shows the problem. solution is here :  https://github.com/goblinfactory/dotnet-sqlitestore

Comment: You indicated that you downloaded the WinRT edition of SQLite, but you have Windows 7.  There isn't a pre-compiled version for Windows 7 - just later versions of Windows.  Make sure you are using the right version!

Comment: Hi @AdrianHall Yes, I agree, ...as far as I know there is no precompiled version for win 7 or earlier. However, the sqlite-winrt-3130000.vsix appears to work a treat on my machine. It's possible It may be working some other way, but I believe it was from that vsix which installed without warning or error. The command line tools and C# test code all works perfectly. It's the Azure wrapper library class that doesnt work, SQLite definately no problem with, see the last sample test above; that  test passes. (using the SQLite WinRT vsix) I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Mobile Apps SDK and tools are only supported with a development environment of Windows 8 or higher. You might be able to get some parts of it working on Windows 7, but we don't support or test that configuration, unfortunately.

You've installed the the package SQLitePCL.bundle_green, but that is **not** the package used by the client SDK, we use [SQLitePCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/). That's why the package install seems to work, but the client library doesn't actually work.

You can run some of the client library unit tests in a .NET 4.5 console app, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client#running-the-tests

Comment: Sob! (thank you for the quick reply) I will have to write a wrapper for the MobileServiceSQLiteStore class using the `managed client for Azure Mobile apps` but that seems like such a waste of effort since surely the Microsoft team would already have such a class that they used for testing when writing the MobileServiceSQLiteStore (msss) class? I can't imagine that every time someone made a change to msss they tested on a droid device? Too slow.

Comment: I am able to run a full end to end testing using NUnit3 Android runner (https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin) this works a treat, but as I've mentioned all along, it requires that a droid app is deployed each time you want to run a test to a physical or vm device, hardly ncrunchable, ...I feel like I've just had a stroke, it's sooo painfully slow way of coding. TDD test results by horse postal delivery. ;-D

Comment: If you want to use Windows 7 (which we don't support), then start from an ISyncTable - when you instantiate a SQLiteSyncTable, you can swap in anything that implements an ISyncTable instead.  The SQLiteSyncTable happens to use SQLitePCL to talk to a SQLite database for this purpose.  Other sync technologies are possible.

Comment: @snowcode The SDK repo has all of the unit tests, which are generally run as a console app on .NET 4.5. There is also a test runner that runs on all of the client platforms. See https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm confused; Ive cloned the repo that @lindydonna-msft referred to; and clearly that's up to date because there have been regular checkins, some as recent as 2 days ago. What's confusing me, is that if you open the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.managed_Windows_VS15 solution (there are several) the main LIB project appears to be `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile`. Ok, so far so good. The odd thing is according to Nuget online, the package with that name hasnt been updated for 2 years? And  `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` is actually the package. Doh! Hope I've missed something. Need 2 trust nuget

Comment: Surely if you're going to rename your nuget package; then you should rename the namespaces in your solutions and projects to match? Or am I just old fashioned? Also; if you're deprecating other nuget packages on the web, then you should update your old deprecated package projects to at very least make a note and explain which nuget package is replacing it? Should be a convention for this, so a human reading proj docs can get full view of the 'current' truth. I even thought about writing a neo4j graph database to help guid folk! #lirally (by folk, I mean `me` of course, he he!

Comment: update: I've posted two issues in the Azure Mobile SDK project on Github and will continue the conversation there, txs all.